# ionic 3 build error when i update CLI from version 3.9 to 4

Tags: android, ionic3

i have a problem when i update my ClI from 3.9.2 to 4.2.1

before

```
cli packages: (/usr/local/lib/node_modules)

    @ionic/cli-utils  : 1.9.2
    ionic (Ionic CLI) : 3.9.2

global packages:

    Cordova CLI : 8.0.0

local packages:

    @ionic/app-scripts : 3.1.8
    Cordova Platforms  : android 7.0.0 ios 4.5.5
    Ionic Framework    : ionic-angular 3.9.2

System:

    Node : v8.12.0
    npm  : 6.4.1
    OS   : macOS Sierra
```

result of **cordova build android**

> ✔ Running command - done!
>   Android Studio project detected
>   ANDROID_HOME=/usr/local/Caskroom/android-platform-tools/27.0.1
>   JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_121.jdk/Contents/Home
>   studio
>   Subproject Path: CordovaLib
>   Subproject Path: app
>   Starting a Gradle Daemon, 2 busy and 1 incompatible Daemons could not be reused, use --status for details

after

```
Ionic:

   ionic (Ionic CLI)  : 4.2.1 (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/ionic)
   Ionic Framework    : ionic-angular 3.9.2
   @ionic/app-scripts : 3.1.8

Cordova:

   cordova (Cordova CLI) : 8.0.0
   Cordova Platforms     : android 7.1.0, ios 4.5.5
   Cordova Plugins       : cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard 2.0.5, cordova
   plugin-ionic-webview 1.2.1, (and 17 other plugins)

System:

   NodeJS : v8.12.0 (/usr/local/bin/node)
   npm    : 6.4.1
   OS     : macOS Sierra
```

result of **cordova build android** =====>

Android Studio project detected
ANDROID_HOME=/usr/local/Caskroom/android-platform-tools/27.0.1
JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_121.jdk/Contents/Home
studio
Starting a Gradle Daemon (subsequent builds will be faster)
:wrapper

BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 11s
1 actionable task: 1 executed
Subproject Path: CordovaLib
Subproject Path: app

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- Where:
  Script '/Users/wsslmac/Desktop/testapk copy 2/platforms/android/CordovaLib/cordova.gradle' line: 68
- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred evaluating project ':CordovaLib'.

  > No installed build tools found. Install the Android build tools version 19.1.0 or higher.
- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 5s
(node:80569) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: /Users/wsslmac/Desktop/testapk copy 2/platforms/android/gradlew: Command failed with exit code 1 Error output:
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- Where:
  Script '/Users/wsslmac/Desktop/testapk copy 2/platforms/android/CordovaLib/cordova.gradle' line: 68
- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred evaluating project ':CordovaLib'.

  > No installed build tools found. Install the Android build tools version 19.1.0 or higher.
- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 5s
    at ChildProcess.whenDone (/Users/wsslmac/Desktop/testapk copy 2/platforms/android/cordova/node_modules/cordova-common/src/superspawn.js:169:23)
    at emitTwo (events.js:126:13)
    at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:214:7)
    at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:915:16)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:209:5)
(node:80569) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 1)
(node:80569) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.enter code here

my android path

```
echo $ANDROID_HOME
==> {/Library/Android/sdk}
```

i never change the sdk and also the android platforms

thnx for help